# Sync folder between Samsung tablet and windows 8 programmatic or via software

Tags: android, windows

What will be good programmatic way to sync folder containing documents from Windows 8 machine to a Samsung tablet.

I was thinking to use

dir > filename.list

And do diff to generate few copy commands.

But i cannot see the Samsung device on the mount or drive.

So what would be good way to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

[Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/home) has an [app for android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dropbox.android).

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question. Doesn't require much effort on your end unless you're specifically trying to program it manually.

Answer (score 0):

I found this app pcfilesync.

It works like charm

https://sites.google.com/a/sergey-bogdanov.info/pcfilesync/tutorial-1